# how to auto center text columns inside browser window?

Tags: css

I want all four columns to be in middle of browser window. i tried with vertical align attribute but it has no effect. what do you guys recommend for this? thanks.

code:

```
center div {width: 150px; display: inline-block; background: lightgray; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; vertical-align: 50%;}

center {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/26n4e/7/

Comment: the columns are in the center?? what is the problem?

Comment: The OP means vertically but isn't being clear.

Comment: Note that the `<center>` element is deprecated, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: Yes I mean vertically centred!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS tables as follows:

Replace the `<center>` element with a standard `div`, and then wrap the content within a `p` tag (or some other block level element):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div><p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Apply the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;

}
.wrapper div {
    width: 150px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.wrapper div p {
    background: lightgray;
    margin: 0;
}
```

see demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/TU8KJ/

You need to set the height to 100% for the `<body>` and `<html>` elements. This will provide a height for the CSS table `.wrapper` and the CSS table-cells `.wrapper div`.

The horizontal centering is due to `margin: 0 auto` on `.wrapper` and the vertical centering is due to `vertical-align: middle` on `.wrapper div`.

Answer (score 1):

to me

```
<center>
```

tag is quite obsolete and should be used only for text/inline elements. If you work with block elements I recommend using workaround "inline-block" and instead go for left/right margin set to **auto** and fixed width, as follows:

```
margin: 0px auto;
width: 600px;
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/26n4e/8/

### EDIT- VERTICALLY!

add this to your center element (fixed height is a must here)

```
position: absolute; margin: auto; padding: 0; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; height: 400px;
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/26n4e/9/

Comment: I need vertical centreing!!

Comment: ahh, right. Sry... vertical/horizontal - big issue for me even after so many years of using english :P